# Reverse regex pattern match - how to tell which pattern matched a result (Bash)

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I have a simple function for looking up tracking numbers written in Bash that works.  I've defined several variables for each pattern variation.  I then use `egrep` to search the file and then output the match.  What I'd like to do is know which pattern matched so I can identify it as part of the output.

```
function gettracking () {

local usps1='[0-9]{20}'
local usps2='[0-9]{4}[[:blank:]][0-9]{4}[[:blank:]]'
# there's several more, but not necessary for the question)

tracking=$(egrep "${usps1}|${usps2}" $1)

if [ -z "${tracking}-x" ]
then
  echo "No tracking found"
else 
  echo "Tracking # ${tracking} sent to clipboard"
  echo ${tracking} | pbcopy    # (this is on macOS BTW)
fi
}
```

I would like to know which of the variables (`$usps1` or `$usps2`, etc.) provided the match so that I can make my output say `The USPS Tracking # is...` or `The FedEx Tracking # is...`

**Is there a way to identify which pattern made the match?**

Comment: Use `grep -o` so you get the matched part, then you can test it in a `case` statement to see which pattern it matches.

Comment: `if [ -z "${tracking}+x" ]` will never be true.

Comment: Can you give me an example of `grep -o`?  I see the output, but how would I match it to a pattern?  I don't need a whole lengthy case statement...just the syntax/example of the conditional would be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep -o` to just get the matched part of the file, then test it with each pattern.

```
match=$(grep -o "${usps1}|${usps2}" $1)
if [[ $match =~ $usps1 ]]
then echo "The USPS tracking number is $tracking"
elif [[ $match =~ $usps2 ]]
then echo "The FedEx tracking number is $tracking"
fi
```